# href is not getting generated when ui-sref is used in angular js ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular js ui router to route my pages, but for some reason href attribute is not getting generated automatically, because of this I couldn't route to my pages,

Please take a look at the code that I have written below

```
mainpage.html
    <a ui-sref="main-page" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cards">

subpage.html
<div class="row">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills col-md-12">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a role="tab" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" ui-sref="main-page.new">
          </a>
      </li>
```

Js Code:

```
.state('main-page',{
        url: '/main-page',
        templateUrl: 'mainpage.html',
        controller: 'mainpageController'
     })

.state('main-page.new',{
        url: '/main-page-new',
        templateUrl: 'main-page-new.html',
        controller: 'mainPageNewController'
    })
```

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem. Also note which versions of angular and ui-router you are using

Comment: @charlietfl Sure, let me do it

Comment: I couldn't create a plunker because of this error : The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Comment: that's  fairly old version of angular. But just change http to https in the src of the script tag

Comment: It isn't working even after changing http to https

Comment: save it and post link to it

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CUTy44XPMopLyzBoZORl?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your plunker demo available here 
https://plnkr.co/edit/CUTy44XPMopLyzBoZORl?p=preview

### index.html

line 2 : missing `ng-app="app"`

line 6 : missing quote after `angular.js`

line 7 : `<scrip` instead of `<script`

### script.js

line 7 : missing dependencies injection. Of course some Gulp/Grunt plugins do it for you but it's good to know how it works ;) :

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
```

You must use this syntax :

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

### Demo

Here is the fixed version of your plunker :
https://plnkr.co/edit/0Hrm5zz4yb17cJEH0XQY?p=preview